# How to convert uint64_t to const char * in C++?

Tags: c++, char-pointer

I have one method which accepts `const char *` as shown below -

```
bool get_data(const char* userid) const;
```

Now below is my for loop in which I need to call `get_data` method by passing `const char *`. Currently below for loop uses `uint64_t`. I need to convert this `uint64_t` to `const char *` and then pass to `get_data` method.

```
for (TmpIdSet::iterator it = userids.begin(); it != userids.end(); ++it) {
    // .. some code
    // convert it to const char *
    mpl_files.get_data(*it)
}
```

Here `TmpIdSet` is `typedef std::set<uint64_t> TmpIdSet;`

So my question is how should I convert `uint64_t` in the above code to `const char *`?

Comment: What do you mean by "converting a number to a pointer"? How do you convert kittens into a happy thought?

Comment: have you tried `ltoa()`?

Comment: Do you actually want the 64 bit integer converted to a string and then passed or do you simply want to change the type (which would probably be undefined behaviour)?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I want the 64 bit integer converted to a string and then passed. Actually C++ is not my first language so don't know much about the predefined functions. I did some search and couldn't find the solution as well.

Comment: A UUID is 128 bit, how are you fitting it into an `uint64_t`?

Comment: sorry that uuid I have is not 128 bit, it is just a variable name in my case. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JerryJeremiah it's well-define to alias a type by a char type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to convert it first to a `std::string` using [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and then access the raw data using the `std::string::c_str()` member function:

```
#include <string>

....

uint64_t integer = 42;
std::string str = std::to_string(integer);
mpl_files.get_data(str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 mpl_files.get_data( std::to_string( *it ).c_str() )
```

Include `<string>` header. For g++ specify `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply cast as const char *:

```
uint64_t integer;
const char * newpointer = (const char *)integer;
```